# Error inflating custom view class in xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 1.0 RC 1 and I'm having trouble inflating a view class in xml file.
I have a view file which extends GridView and which contains all 3 constructors:

```
package app.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ImageSeGridView extends GridView {

    public ImageSeGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageSeGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageSeGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //....
    }
}
```

and I'm adding this view inside xml class:

```
<app.views.ImageSeGridView
        android:id="@+id/image_search_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I'm not getting any complains at compile time, but at running I receive the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class app.views.ImageSeGridView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
```

and I do not know how to solve this issue. This does not occur when using IntelliJ IDEA 13 for example, happens only when using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are targeting 21, but this is what I have been doing lately.

```
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

@TargetApi(21)
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}
```

Quick Edit: Also, I use fully qualified package names for my elements - com.company.appname.views.widgets.customview etc in my layouts. I am not sure if that is the full extent of your package name

Comment: Hey, I'm targeting 19 and I do not have a constructor with 4 parameters :( The package name is just informative, is not the real one I'm using it.